# How to set ConstraintLayout at full screen ignoring system bars in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to set ConstraintLayout size as the device size ignoring system bars, bottom nav bars etc. because when I start session in my fitness app i'm using immersive mode and my UI in ConstraintLayout start to recompose it's position because of new avaliable free space on the screen but i want it to be fixed always.

I'm using `ConstraintLayout(Modifier.height(LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeight.dp))` but it doesn't work. When app turn into immersive mode my layout still stretch. Can we take somehow size as at picture?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

In themes.xml

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

In activity where you set you navigation graph

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = getNavigationController()
            ChildMeditationTheme {
                fullScreen()
            }
        }
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
        )
    }

@Composable
private fun fullScreen() {
    // Remember a SystemUiController
    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
    val useDarkIcons = !isSystemInDarkTheme()
    systemUiController.isNavigationBarVisible = false // Navigation bar
    val windowInsetsController =
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
    // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
    windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
    windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
    DisposableEffect(systemUiController, useDarkIcons) {
        // Update all of the system bar colors to be transparent, and use
        // dark icons if we're in light theme
        systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
            color = Color.Transparent,
            darkIcons = useDarkIcons
        )
        systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(
            color = Color.Transparent,
            darkIcons = useDarkIcons
        )
        systemUiController.setNavigationBarColor(
            color = Color.Transparent,
            darkIcons = useDarkIcons
        )
        onDispose {}
    }
}
```

In constraint layout set this modifier

```
ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried `fillMaxSize()` already. Doesn't help. I have bottom nav in MainActivity and hide it when session started. Maybe it's resizing because of this nav bar

Comment: you need to define full screen flags like I posted the code. I also wanted full screen with constriantlayout and I have posted the same code which I have used.